# C# WinForm Keypress only allow two numbers after full stop

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a WinForm with keypress which allows individuals to enter a number in a textbox.

I allow users to enter one full stop however how can i do it so they can only enter two numbers after the full stop. for example "20.99"

Comment: What's the connection between the numbers and the Keypress event? Some info is missing here.

Comment: I want it so individuals are limited on the amount of numbers after the full stop. for example now they can enter "20.99999" however i only want it so they can only enter two numbers after the full stop, i.e "20.99"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) control exists for just such cases.

> The MaskedTextBox class is an enhanced TextBox control that supports a declarative syntax for accepting or rejecting user input.

Comment: It looks like we are slowly getting back the functionality of VB6 controls. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MarkHall - I know... funny really, when you think about it.

Comment: Odd, two posts making the same wrong claim.  MaskedTextBox has been around much longer, click the "Other versions" dropdown box in the page you linked.

Comment: @HansPassant - I didn't see the drop down, looks like the unobtrusive javascript rendering it is a bit slow on my machine.

Comment: I'll never understand why so many SO users use the web version of MSDN.  Those seconds add up quickly.